# Use a window.prototype function in javascript

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a issue in webapp, i am using webcomponentsjs this lib override

```
    mixin(Window.prototype, {
      getComputedStyle: function(el, pseudo) {
           renderAllPending();
           return originalGetComputedStyle.call(unwrap(this), 
                   unwrapIfNeeded(el), pseudo);
       },
       getSelection: function() {
           renderAllPending();
           return new Selection(originalGetSelection.call(unwrap(this)));
       },
       get document() {
           return wrap(unwrap(this).document);
       }
});
if (originalGetDefaultComputedStyle) {
        Window.prototype.getDefaultComputedStyle = function(el, pseudo) {
              renderAllPending();
              return originalGetDefaultComputedStyle.call(unwrap(this), 
                      unwrapIfNeeded(el), pseudo);
       };
}
```

then i use jspanel that use getComputedStyle but in firefox and IE not works

Somebody have any idea about how can i use the original getComputedStyle??

Thank

Comment: Ow man, can't you just indent the code so that it is readable?

Comment: Why do you think Window.getComputedStyle() does not work in FF and IE? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#Browser_compatibility